# Problems with locale url using Docusaurus

Tags: docusaurus

I followed the documentation on the docusaurus website to add an i18n locale dropdown. By default my website is in spanish and I'm trying to implement an English translation. On my computer it works perfectly, but when it's deployed to our staging server the implementation breaks.

Anytime the english button on the dropdown is clicked it tries to go to the /en/docs page and it shows the custom 404 and when you click it again it routes to /en/en/docs and it keeps appending /en/ at the beginning of the url.

Any ideas what could be causing the problem?

Also, our team uses dokku for this project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this issue it could be the way the app is being served to the user. I replicated this problem ussing `npm start` and then made a two step docker deployment where one builds the app and the other displays the "build" folder